# What does it mean to be a positioned element?

Tags: html, css

I couldn't find information that helps me on Google... I'll appreciate any help
What does it mean to be a positioned element?

1. Unlike non-positioned elements, a positioned element can have its position adjusted/set by the positioning properties (top, left, bottom, right, and z-index )
2. Positioned elements ignore font- and text- properties

1 or 2? And an explanation will be great :)

Thank you.

Comment: What information are you looking for beyond what any of the first 5 hits on Google provides? [For example](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position `A positioned element is an element whose computed position value is either relative, absolute, fixed, or sticky. (In other words, it's anything except static.)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A positioned element is taken OUT of the normal DOM flow (this means it's not dependent on other elements for its position on the screen).

Dom elements with CSS `position: absolute | fixed` are considered to be positioned. The default value is of "nothing" is similar to `position: relative` meaning "relative to the page flow".

*Note* a positioned element without any coordinate attributes specified eg: `top | right | left | bottom` will act like a `position: relative` element in most browsers.

Contrary to what's stated in #2 positioned elements DO respond to CSS attributes like `font-size, font-weight, text-transform` just as any other element would.

Comment: `A positioned element is taken OUT of the normal DOM flow` --> a positon:relative is also a positioned element and is not taken out of the normal flow